# tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.pb.h file not found Error for iOS TensorFlow Camera App

Tags: ios, tensorflow

When I go to run the TensorFlow iOS Camera app example I receive a 'tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.pb.h file not found' error.  I have ran the download_dependcies.sh and compile_ios_protobuf.sh before running compile_ios_tensorflow and I still am receiving the error.  Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQKMQ.png)

Comment: have you found any solution for this missing file. Please do share it in answer if your have found it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you're hitting problems! Could you try running tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh to make sure everything's built, and then file a github issue if it's still having issues?

Comment: Thanks, when I run I receive this error:   configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the files with Google's protocol buffer application.

I copied the resource_handle.proto to the application directory.
Ran:
    protoc.exe resource_handle.proto --cpp_out=.
copied the resulting resource_handle.pb.[cc][h] files back.

See:  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/